# How to run a Jenkins job inside a windows docker container

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile, docker-machine, dock

I am trying to run a jenkins job inside a windows docker container. I have successfully created an image with windows server code docker image which will have MSBuildEngine 4.7.

The problem I am facing is I am not able to run a Jenkins job inside that container.

I am able to do it easily with linux environment.

The actual problem is, Jenkins first puts a shell file which will have the command to run the container and inspect it.

How do I tell Jenkins that my environment is not Linux and it is Windows.

Note: Searching in google does not help now a days. So I directly reached out here

Answer (score 0):

I am working on this issue as well. I am finding that the (maybe just a) underlying issue is how Jenkins tells Docker to mount a volume to the container. I have yet to get around this issue.

edit:

There's a [PR](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/pull/148) addressing this issue and I tested the fork with both Linux and Windows slaves to work as we intend.

1. Download Rbutcher's fork of the plugin:

   - `git clone https://github.com/rbutcher/docker-workflow-plugin.git`
2. Change to the working branch:

   - `git checkout feat/windows_slaves`
3. Build the plugin:

   - `mvn -DskipTests clean install`
4. Manually import into Jenkins:

   - Manage Jenkins> Manage Plugins> Advanced>Upload Plugin and select `./target/docker-workflow.hpi`.